# WIX copying files harvested by heat, but does not create cab file

Tags: wix, windows-installer, cab, wix3.10

Fairly new to Wix. I have a working msi, but instead of a cab file next to the msi file, I am just getting a folder. I have spent several days trying to figure out why it is not putting the files in a cab file but I am completely at a loss.

The msi file performs exactly as I expect, but distributing the msi alongside a folder is less desirable than just the msi.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="[Name]" Language="1033" Manufacturer="[Manufacturer]" Version="2.0.30" 
         UpgradeCode="af66ae21-61e4-4926-954d-ee89acf95ab3">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200"/>

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [Name] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate/>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="[Title]" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcut" />
      <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="WebApp" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ControlApp" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
        <Directory Id="ManufacturerName" Name="[Name]">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="[Name]" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
    <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="[Name]"/>
    <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop"></Directory>
  </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>
<Fragment>
<DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
 <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="844b584d-6d5f-4825-9541-c7caf74892fb">
   <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut" 
             Name="[Name]" 
             Description="[Name]" 
             Target="[INSTALLLOCATION]MyApp.exe" 
             WorkingDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION" />
   <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveApplicationProgramsFolder" Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall" />
   <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Name]" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
 </Component>
</DirectoryRef>   
<DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
 <Component Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" Guid="629d0ac6-8c63-4309-af33-975925584d1f">
   <Shortcut Id="ApplicationDesktopShortcut" 
             Name="[Name]" 
             Description="[Name]" 
             Target="[INSTALLLOCATION]MyApp.exe" 
             WorkingDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION" />
   <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveDesktopFolder" Directory="DesktopFolder" On="uninstall" />
   <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Name]" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
 </Component>
   </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `Package/@Compressed` attribute to `yes`.

Comment: Beautiful! The larger project has some powershell code that is designed to keep the version numbers between each project the same. When I was building it, I fubar'd my Package element and I didn't notice the Compressed attribute had been removed. Adding it back corrected the issue. Thanks!